# Mapping is not happening when project is mavenized

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jboss

I am using a EAR architecture type project with spring framework on jboss 6.1EAP, Initially, when my project was not mavenized it was working fine and all the mapping was going fine( as can see in the server logs) But as soon as I mavenize my project all the mapping which maps the controllers are gone (No Mapping at all). How to resolve this ? what I am doing wrong ?

I am using M2E plugin in eclipse

POM for application  :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aseParent</groupId>
    <artifactId>aseParent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>ASE</description>

    <modules>
        <module>ase</module>
        <module>aseEAR</module>
    </modules>


    <build>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.4.Final</version>


            <configuration>

            <jbossHome>D:\jboss-eap-6.1.0\jboss-eap-6.1</jbossHome>

            <jvmArgs>-Djava.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider=sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorProvider</jvmArgs>

            </configuration>

 </plugin> 





        </plugins>
    </build>
```

POM for WebApp:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spring_test</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

POM for EAR:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spring_testEAR</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_testEAR</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <earSourceDirectory>EarContent</earSourceDirectory>
          <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
          <version>6</version>
          <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Post your pom and other relevant configs.

Comment: Here is all the POM files attached as per the request

Comment: Why are you not following the defaults `src/main/java`, resources `src/main/resources`, unit tests `src/test/java`, test resources `src/test/resources` it simply does not make sense. Apart from that you should check your project on command line if it working correctly. Not within Eclipse. If it's working you can go into Eclipse...